# SOQL Query by External ID is missing records

Tags: soql, externalid

I'm having a problem consistently querying an object by an external id. When I do a SOQL query that has a queryplan that uses an index on the externalID,  the record can not always be found. It is as though the index is corrupt, but I have no way to force a rebuild.

My minimum example:

I have a field named `PID` on the standard `Contact` object. `PID` is defined as autonumber (format p{00000}) and flagged as external ID.

For brevity, assume I have exactly two contact records with salesforce ids of 'record1' and 'record2' (I'm not going to try to type the real ones). The name fields of these two records contain 'name1' and name2' respectively.

Through the salesforce.com UI, I can search the names and find

```
Name: name1
PID: P00000
```

and

```
Name: name2
PID: P00001
```

In the force.com developer console,

```
query: select id, pid__c, name where name='name1'
result: 
record1,'P00000','name1'

query: select id, pid__c, name where id='record1'
result:
record1,'P00000','name1'

query: select id,pid__c,name where pid__c >= 'p0000'
result:
record1,'P00000','name1'
record2,'P00001','name2'

query: select id, pid__c, name where pid__c = 'P00001'
result:
record1,'P00001','name2'
```

****** BUT *******

```
query: select id,pid__c,name where pid__c='P00000'
result:
<no rows>
```

There are actually about 8000 rows in this table with a bunch of other fields and externalIDs, but no duplicate PIDs since that's an autonumber field.

I haven't been able to detect a pattern as to which records can and cannot be located by PID. Some, like P00001 in this example, can be found and some, like P00000, can not. If a record can be found by PID once, it can always be found. If it can not be found by PID on the first attempt, it will never be findable.

Ideas, anyone?

Thanks
-Jim

Comment: There aren't any odd character issues going on with the ID by chance? It could be as simple as a `O` rather than a `0` in the id. Or it could be a more exotic encoding issue with characters that look correct but are on another code page. If you copy and paste the external id value from the actual record to the SOQL query does it work?

Comment: Oh, it's an autonumber field, so it shouldn't contain any character encoding oddities. How about if you attempt an upsert via the API and use the problem PID__c as the externalIdFieldName. It should become an update as the matching record is found (which I assume will use the index).

Comment: Last idea, compare the [Execution Plan](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000199003&language=en_US) between the query that works and the one that doesn't. There might be a clue there.

Comment: Just curious if you drop the WHERE clause if it will show the records in question. If so, instead of using the equal operator what returns if you were to use the like operator?

Comment: Are there any sharing rules at play here? Are you sure that the user you have logged in as has right to access the Contact record with PID 'P00000' and not just the record with 'p00001'?

Comment: I have faced similar behavior in Apex, but that was only happening in Sandbox.

Comment: Wondering if this is still going on, or if you got any resolution?

Answer (score 2):

This is known issue.

Remove and Recreate the External Id and unique properties of the custom field should resolve the issue.
If the field is a custom indexed field, reach out to support for rebuilding the index on the field.

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193737&language=en_US